# Is there a known issue with drop down menus in CefSharp WPF

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

With the latest version of `CefSharp (71)` and using the `WPF` version, when I open a `dropdown` list and scroll with the mouse as soon as scrolling stops the drop down is closed.

I have downloaded the latest `MinimalExample` and then navigated to [This drop down test site.](http://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/select-dropdown-menu/).  I observe the same behaviour with the `WPF` example, but do not with the `windowsforms` example.

**Update Based on Comment**
I have also tested the same website with the CEF Automated Build cef_binary_3.3578.1864.gfa073f3_windows32_client and the drop downs work as expected.

Is this a known issue? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Test with the CEF sample application see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-chromium-embedded-frameworkcef for details

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I have done that and updated the questions.  I also tested it with CEFSharp WinForms and there is also no strange behaviour there.

Comment: Please test with the CEF sample application as requested. CefSharp is a wrapper around the chromium embedded framework.

Comment: What command line args did you test with?

Comment: All tests both with CefSharp MinimalExample WinForms/Wpf and with CEF Automated Builds were tested simply as downloaded. No changes at all. I simply compiled and ran then navigated to the test page. What should I try?

Comment: As per the link I posted you need to test with cefclient --multi-threaded-message-loop --off-screen-rendering-enabled --enable-gpu

Comment: Short term the only workaround is to host the `WinForms` version in `WPF`. I think you'll find this is a bug in `CEF`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I tested cefclient with the args and it does the same thing.  I am assuming this means it is a CEF (upstream) issue right?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to raise the issue upstream

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have asked in the CEF forum.